# Ubuntu Paragon FS Login Loop

Tags: 18.04, gnome, xorg, gdm, xserver

I haven't recently updated Ubuntu or anything, it was working perfectly fine, until it suddenly refused to log me into desktop anymore. Whenever I login, it pauses for seconds, then brings the login screen again.

I've seen countless questions/articles/threads on the Internet explaining how to fix this, but sadly nothing has worked for me yet. I've even turned to second Google results page... Do you imagine?

Anyways, the only thing I recognize that could f**k up my machine is installing these two
http://www.ext2fsd.com/
and

https://www.paragon-software.com/home/linuxfs-windows/

installed by that order. Ext2Fsd didn't work for me, so I had to resort to Paragon's solution instead. The login loop problem only appeared after using these programs. I tried opening them, unmounting everything, remounting in read-only in hopes of reverting something that could've f**ked up, to no avail.

Of the many solutions that I found, one command seems to be very weird, which is `strace xauth list`, it almost always fails, either by telling me there's no .Xauthority file (after deliberately deleting it while following some article's advice), or just spitting walls of text that just look like a logcat.

I also tried doing strace startx, but it always complains that Xauthority could not be read, permission denied, and the whole tty blacks out, that I need to start another tty to continue tinkering. (EDIT Oct: It doesn't black out, it's just loading serverx and takes ages, after some time it either loads it as sudo, or fails and brings back the tty)

I don't even know where to start debugging, and how to debug. I hope someone can help me.

**NOTE**: Someone suggested that the home directory could be encrypted, and to install ecryptfs-utils to fix it, I did so but didn't change a thing.

**EDIT**: Running `df -hl` shows that sda6 or / has 6% free, which is 34 GB.

**EDIT**: I tried installing LightDM instead of GDM3, but it has the same issue of redirecting back to login screen. I guess this eliminates the possibility of DM issues.

**EDIT**: I tried running `sudo prime-select intel`, but it didn't solve anything, I believe this means there's no problem with my NVIDIA card? Side note: I use **bumblebee**.

**EDIT**: Not really sure if this is needed, but I'd love to document everything. When I reboot the system and go into tty again, entering username automatically inserts another new line, which is directed to the password field, and it complains that the new line is a wrong password. It keeps looping this until it restarts/cleans the tty and asks for username again. The only solution to this is rebooting into the previous linux version, then rebooting into the current one again. But a reboot on the same version will introduce it and the loop goes on.

Comment: You've documented many things that could now complicate things.  If you've had no updates, installed nothing new nor changed any hardware but can no longer login - the first thing I check is I have space in $HOME (your user directory). If it's full or very-near-full a GUI login cannot proceed as it can't create temporary work files needed for gui operation, and you return to greeter/login screen.  Login using a terminal and `df -hl` (disk free - local drives, human output) & check you have space (text logins will work).  This changes nothing, but eliminates one (primary) cause.

Comment: Check edited post, it shows I have 34 gigs left in root

Comment: I said $HOME (/home/user/) which may be on a separate partition, and then (more unlikely) i'd also check inodes you didn't mention.

Comment: Well I can't find $HOME in the output.. The only recognizable entries are
/dev
/run
/
/dev/shm
/run/lock
/sys/fs/cgroup
/boot/efi
/run/user/120
/run/user/1000

rest is a bunch of weird /dev/loop#

Comment: `df -h |grep $HOME`  or if you want to see what $HOME represents you could `echo $HOME`.   To view inodes you use the -i option with `df`.  *Of note if you create problems on your system, they don't show until you next boot it, as for example, if you delete (`rm`) a needed file that was being used at the time, the file won't be noticed until next reboot or next login, but the current session can still use it as the inode isn't freed until the session ends (thru logout or off/reset)*

Comment: grep home doesn't return a line, grep my username the same, echoing $HOME shows the correct home directory, but there's absolutely nothing about it in `df -h` or `df -hl` or using -i... Could that be a problem?

Comment: @guiverc I tried running du -sh /home, it outputs 425G, and my linux partition is 513G in total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the exact same thing happen to me after installing Paragons LinuxFS software. It changes file permissions on the disk despite checking the read-only option when mounting the ext4 drive.

The login loop is caused by not having write permissions in your home directory.
The command `chmod u+rwx` will fix this issue. However there is no telling what other damage Paragons software has done to your files. So I'd suggest uninstalling Paragon LinuxFS and doing a fresh install of Ubuntu.

Comment: This worked... Finally I can boot into Ubuntu...! (Yes I left it untouched since April :D)